# d3.js: Confusion about the order in which the code is executed

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, global-variables

I am trying to make an interactive bar chart in D3.js
I [uploaded everything to github](https://github.com/Federicopvs/stateBankExposition.git) for easy reference. I also included index.html at the end of my question.

My starting point is data.json containing an array of 7 items (i.e. countries). Each country has an attribute 'name' and four other attributes. These represent the exposition of private banks and the state to Greek debt for the years 2009 and 2014.

My goal is to create a bar chart that starts by showing the exposition of each country's banks and public sector in 2009 (so two bars for each country) and that changes to the year 2014 once the user clicks on the appropriate button.

I had managed to make it all work nicely! However, I had to create manually separate lists for each (sub-)dataset I needed to use. For example I created one called y2009 which included the exposition of bank and state for country 1, then the same for country 2, an so on..
(I left one of the list and commented it out on line 43)

I wanted to make my code more flexible so I created a for loop that extracts the data and creates the lists for me. (see lines 46-60). This did not work because the for loops would start before the data was actually loaded. Hence I would end up with empty lists.
So I grouped the for loops into a function (prepare()) and executed that function within the function that loads the data (lines 18-30). This fixed that issue...

..and created a new one! The two functions that should set the scales (see lines 67-73) do not work because their calculations require on one of the lists created by the for loops (namely 'total').
(I assume this is due to the list being created after the scale methods are called.)

The curious thing is that if I run the script, then copy in the console the xScale and yScale functions, and then copy the draw function (lines 101-212) everything works.
Hence I tried to group everything into functions (e.g. setScales, draw) so that I would call them in the order I want at the end of the script (lines 214-215) but this creates problem because certain variables (e.g. xScale and yScale) need to be global.
I also tried to first create them in the global space and then modify them through setScales. This did not work either.

Summing up, wait I don't understand is:

- In which order should I write the code to make things work(again)? Is it a good idea to wrap operations within functions (e.g. setting the scales, drawing bars and labels) and then calling the function in the right order?
- Which type of object is created with the scale method? I am confused on whether they are actual functions.

I hope this was not too much of a pain to read and thank everyone who made it through!

Fede

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Introductory text here!</p>

<p>
<button id="change2009"> 2009 </button>
<button id="change2014"> 2014 </button>
</p>

<div id="country"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else{
    console.log(json);
    dataset=json;
    }

prepare (dataset);

});

//load data
var dataset;
var bank09=[];
var state09=[];
var bank14=[];
var state14=[];
var y2009=[];
var y2014=[];
var total=[];
var xScale;
var yScale;
//var total = [4.76, 0, 0.12, 6.36, 4.21, 0, 0.04, 7.96, 78.82, 0, 1.81, 46.56, 45, 0, 13.51, 61.74, 6.86, 0, 1.06, 40.87, 12.21, 0, 1.22, 13.06, 1.21, 0, 0.39, 27.35];


function prepare (dataset){
    for (i in dataset) {bank09.push(dataset[i].bank09);
    state09.push(dataset[i].state09);
    bank14.push(dataset[i].bank14);
    state14.push(dataset[i].state14);
    y2009.push(dataset[i].bank09);
    y2009.push(dataset[i].state09);
    y2014.push(dataset[i].bank14);
    y2014.push(dataset[i].state14); 
    total.push(dataset[i].bank09);
    total.push(dataset[i].state09);
    total.push(dataset[i].bank14);
    total.push(dataset[i].state14);
    }
}

//overwrite dataset
dataset2=y2009;

//scales
function setScales () {
    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
              .domain(d3.range(total.length/2))
              .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.1);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0, d3.max(total)])
              .range([0, h]);
    console.log(yScale(89));
}

//layout
var w = 600;
var h = 600;
var barPadding = 1;

//coountry names
var country = ["Austria", "Belgium", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Holland", "Spain"];

d3.select("#country")
    .data(country)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "country")
    //.append("text")
    //.text(function(d){
    //    return d;
    //  })


//draw svg
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

function draw () {
//draw bars
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset2)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d){
        return h - yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("fill", "black");


//add labels
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset2)
    .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d){
                return d;
            })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "12px")
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("x", function(d, i){
         return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
         })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
     if (d<3) {
       return h - 15;
       } else {
         return h - yScale(d) + 15;}
         })


  //interactivity
  d3.select("#change2014")
    .on("click", function() {
    //update data
    dataset2=y2014;
    //update bars
    svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset2)
       .transition()
       .duration(3000)
       .attr("y", function(d){
       return h - yScale(d);
       })
       .attr("height", function(d) {
       return yScale(d);
       })        
    //update labels
    svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(dataset2)
      .transition()
      .duration(3000)          
      .text(function(d){
        return d;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d, i){
        return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        if (d<3) {
          return h - 15;
        } else {
          return h - yScale(d) + 15;}
      })
    })


  d3.select("#change2009")
    .on("click", function() {
    //update data
    dataset2=y2009;
    //update bars
    svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset2)
       .transition()
       .duration(3000)           
       .attr("y", function(d){
       return h - yScale(d);
       })
       .attr("height", function(d) {
       return yScale(d);
       })
    //update labels
    svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(dataset2)
      .transition()
      .duration(3000)          
      .text(function(d){
        return d;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d, i){
        return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        if (d<3) {
          return h - 15;
        } else {
          return h - yScale(d) + 15;}
      })
    })
}

setScales ();
draw();
</script>
```

Comment: Put *all* the code that relies on the data into the `d3.json` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In which order should I write the code to make things work(again)? Is
>   it a good idea to wrap operations within functions (e.g. setting the
>   scales, drawing bars and labels) and then calling the function in the
>   right order?

As Lars pointed out, you can put everything inside the d3.json callback. This is because you only want to start rendering with D3 once you have the data. The d3.json method is asynchronous, which means that after you call d3.json(), the code afterwards will execute first before the function inside the d3.json method has finished. Check out http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/ for more on asynchronous behavior in Javascript.

Given that you only want to start rendering when the d3.json method has completed, you could also just organize the other parts of your code into smaller functions and call some sort of initializer function from within the d3.json success callback, sort of like what you are doing with the prepare function. This is a cleaner approach and starts taking you towards a model-view paradigm.

> Which type of object is created with the scale method? I am confused
>   on whether they are actual functions.

The scale method does return a function, but with additional functions added to its prototype. Try printing out "someScale.prototype" to see all of the various methods you can use. I'd also highly recommend Scott Murray's tutorial on D3. Here is the chapter on scales: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the answers!! I managed to solve the problem by wrapping methods in functions and then calling the functions in the right order within the data.json

Moreover I found out that, if I removed var when setting xScale and yScale within the setScales function, they would become global variables, thus solving all referencing issues.